# Prove that $ \frac{4}{x(4-x)} \geq 1 $ if $ 0 < x < 4 $

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation

From the Book of Proof, Chapter 4, exercise 12, I need to prove that $ \frac{4}{x(4-x)} \geq 1 $ if $ 0 < x < 4 $ where x is a real number. Unfortunately, even-numbered exercises don't offer a solution so I don't know if my approach is correct.

The proof I wrote is: We know that any real number squared is greater or equal to zero. We choose a real number (x-2) within the interval $ 0 < x < 4 $.

$$
(x-2)^2 \geq 0 \\
x^2-4x+4 \geq 0 \\
4 \geq 4x-x^2 \\
4 \geq x(4-x) \\
\frac{4}{x(4-x)} \geq 1
$$

My main doubt with the proof is the initial assumption that:

> We know that any real number squared is greater or equal to zero. We choose a real number (x-2) within the interval $ 0 < x < 4 $

As I don't know if I can use this knowledge for the proof. Otherwise I stuck on how to start from the given information that $ 0 < x < 4 $ and reach $ (x-2)^2 \geq 0 $

Comment: The reason you need $0 < x < 4$ is so that $x(4 - x)$ is positive.  Between lines 5 and 6 of your solution, you divide by $x(4 - x)$, which would swap the direction of the inequality if $x(4 - x)$ was negative.

Comment: The issue you need to worry about is not that $(x-2)^2 \ge 0$.  You *do* know that absolutely is always true because all squares are non-negative.  And your proof *does* follow fine up to $4\ge x(4-x)$.  That is *always* true for *any* possible $x$.  It's true for *huge* positive $x$. ($4 \ge 1568(4-1568)=1568\cdot(-1564)=-1568\cdot1564$). It is true for small positives ($4\ge 3(4-3)=3$) and it's true for all negatives ($4\ge -2(4-(-2))=-2\cdot 6=-12$).  The issue is the *next* step when you divide by $x(4-x)$ and not flip the $\ge$ sign.  You can only do that if $x(4-x)>0$.  So... to be cont.

Comment: Essentially the core of you proof is to prove that $0< x < 4\implies x(4-x) > 0$.  That's the key thing, and it is the one thing you have left out of your proof.

Comment: Hi @fleablood, I was taking that into account when dividing by $ x(4-x) $ and not changing the equality sign. Doing that I'm creating a constraint there of x not 0, x not 4 and x(4-x) > 0. Wouldn't that be correct?

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to why you think you might *not* be allowed to use "every square of a real number is greater than or equal to $0$".  But if you are not allowed to do that just reinvent the wheel and proof it all over again.  If $(x-2) > 0$ then $(x-2)^2 > 0$.  If $x-2 = 0$ then $(x-2) = 0$.  And if $x-2 < 0$ then $2-x > 0$ and $(x-2)^2 = [-(2-x)]^2 = -(2-x)^2\cdot[-(2-x)]=(2-x)^2> 0$.  But if you *KNOW* something is true you are allowed to use it and it is *not* an assumption.

Comment: It's now clear to me that I can use that knowledge. However, now I'm quite confused with your proof of $ x-2 > 0 $ as you end up with $ (2-x)^2 > 0 $?

Comment: @fleablood I believe there are some errors in your previous comment?

Comment: I'm not attempting to prove $x-2 > 0$.  That's not true.  I'm just trying to say: If for some reason you think you are *not* allowed to assume $M^2 \ge 0$ for all $M$ then.... just prove $(x-2)^2 \ge 0$.  Just reinvent the wheel.  There are three cases:  Either 1) $x-2 > 0$, if so $(x-2)^2 > 0$ and we are done.  or 2) $x-2 = 0$, if so then $(x-2)^2 = 0$ and we are done.  or 3) $x-2 < 0$.  If so then $2-x > 0$ and $(x-2)^2 = (2-x)^2 > 0$ and we are done.  We just re-proved the $(x-2)^2 \ge 0$ for all $x$.  ... Of course we didn't *NEED* to do that.  But if we did, we could.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now I understood your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is correct, and you did use the information in the last step.  When you divided by $x(4-x)$, to preserve the sense of the inequality, you must have $x(4-x)>0$, which is equivalent to $0 < x < 4$.

Answer (score 1):

You can *absolutely* assume $(x-2)^2 \ge 0$ because $M^2 \ge 0$ *always*.

And the first four lines of your proof are *always* true.

$(x-2)^2 \ge 0$.  That is *always* true.

$x^2 -4x + 4 \ge 0$.  That is *always* true.

$4 \ge 4x -x^2= x(4-x)$.  That is *always* true.

No admittedly that does *look* like it ought to *always* be true but it is!  And you *just* proved it!!!  (Notice that $y=x(4-x)$ is a parabola that opens downward.  For $x < 0$ and $x > 4$ the values are negative and the hit maximum value when $x=2$ of $y = 4$)

So $4 \ge x(4-x)$ is *ALWAYS* true.

Our concern about what range of $x$ can be in only becomes an issue on the next step when you *divide* by $x(4-x)$ and you *don't* "flip the inequality".  This is only possible if $x(4-x)> 0$.  If $x(4-x) = 0$ you can't divide at all.  And if $x(4-x) < 0$ then you'd have to flip the inequality when you divide.

So *that* is the issue of why we have to take $0< x < 4$ into consideration.  We have to *also* prove that if $0 < x< 4 \implies x(x-4) > 0$.  That is the only part of your proof you didn't address.

But that part is easy.  If $0 < x < 4$ then $x > 0$ and $4-x > 0$ so $x(x-4) > 0$.

Now your proof can go like this.

$(x-2)^2 \ge 0$.  This is always true.

$x^2 -4x + 4 \ge 0$.  This is always true.

$4 \ge 4x - x^2 = x(4-x)$. This is always true.

$4 \ge x(4-x) > 0$.  This is *NOT* always true but it *is* true if $x >0$ *and* $x<4$.

$\frac 4{x(4-x)} \ge 1$.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is right, but I thought I would contribute the obligatory AM-GM-HM inequality solution: consider the means of $x$ and $4-x$, which are both positive for $0 < x < 4.$

$$\text{HM} \leq \text{AM} \Rightarrow \frac2{\frac1x + \frac1{4-x}} \leq \frac{x + (4-x)}2 = 2$$

yielding

$$\frac1x + \frac1{4-x} = \frac{4}{x(4-x)} \geq 1$$